# Define methods for multiple classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods

I'm working on a small personal project where I created many classes. Each class has its own register containing all its instances:

```
class IterReg(type):
    # Register of all objects for iteration
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._reg.values())
```

The "template" which I use for each class is

```
class Point(object):
    # Point object
    __metaclass__ = IterReg
    _reg = dict()
    counter = 0

    # Initialize
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._reg[self.name] = self
        Point.counter += 1

    # Return register keys
    @staticmethod
    def get_reg_keys(cls):
        return cls._reg.keys()
```

And some other (not important for a MWE) stuff.
If I initialize, e.g., `a = Point("Point A")`, I can then call:

```
>>> a.get_reg_keys()
['Point A']
```

which is (obviously) the same result that I get from

```
Point.get_reg_keys()
```

Now my question: is there a way to define this method once for all classes (i.e. somehow in the `metaclass`).
I first thought something like this had worked:

```
class IterReg(type):
    # Register of all objects for iteration
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._reg.values())

    def get_reg_keys(cls):
        return cls._reg.keys()
```

But then I can just call `get_reg_keys()` from the class (i.e. `Point.get_reg_keys()`) and not from any instance of it.

Comment: Why not just create a base class (say `RegisteredBase`) that has your `get_reg_keys` method and the generic `__init__` method? Then just subclass your `Point` class from that.

Comment: `Point.get_reg_keys()` is the correct way to call that static function, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a generic class that has `.get_reg_keys()` and subclass it when you want to use that method.  In the below example, any class that inherits from `Generic` will have the `.get_reg_keys()` method.

```
class IterReg(type):
    # Register of all objects for iteration
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._reg.values())

class Generic(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_reg_keys(cls):
        return cls._reg.keys()

class Point(Generic):
    # Point object
    __metaclass__ = IterReg
    _reg = dict()
    counter = 0

    # Initialize
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._reg[self.name] = self
        Point.counter += 1


a = Point('Point A')
a.get_reg_keys()
# returns:
['Point A']
```