# possible multiple inheritance?

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I'm trying to make multiple classes that will use the same set of defintions that already exist in my code.

```
class FT_Ten(PrinterInterface):
    name = "Big Foot"
    QueryCmd = "M107"
    ActionCmd = "M108"

    def __init__(self, device="/dev/ttyACM0"):
         self.device = device

    def hexformat(self, string): 
        out = "".join("{:x}".format(ord(x)) for x in string)
        return out

    def _console_print(self, line):
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Theres about 90 more lines of code for this class. I need to add three more classes that share these definitions. The only differences are in the first few lines. Name, QueryCmd, and ActionCmd. 
Ive tried simply breaking the the code at the begining of the definitions but im only familiar using a single class at a time.
How can i add more classes and use all the definitions that followed the first?

I've looked here trying to figure this out.. 
[Define methods for multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189066/define-methods-for-multiple-classes)

Comment: My main problem is how do I reference the printer name from the new class I create. I need to move the new class above the models but the definitions need to reference the model names, which wont be until later. Do i need to move the with class defintions to another module?

Comment: Why do you think multiple inheritance would be at all useful here?  Certainly, you should have something like a `BasicPrinter` class that contains all of the common stuff (or put in in your existing `PrinterInterface` class), and then derive your four specific printer classes from that one.

Comment: I saw another example awhile back that seemed to offer a clean solution. I shoukd have bookmarked it when i saw it.

Comment: If I add it to printerinterface, then i keep def __init__ with each of the new printer classes, correct?  I've tried moving the definitions to the same module as printerinterface, but I get this error. Nameerror sel fis not defined.